# From Apex server data is not coming to Aura components

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura-attribute, aura-iteration

apex wrapper :

```java
public with sharing class DemoWrapper {

    public  class Timesheet{
        @AuraEnabled public String employeeId {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String employeeName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public List<AddressWrapper> Addresslist {get;set;}
        
        /** constructor */

        public  Timesheet(){
             employeeId = '';
             employeeName = '';
             Addresslist = new List<AddressWrapper>();
        }
    }

    public class AddressWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled public String Street1 {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String Street2 {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String city {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String state {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String pincode {get;set;}

        /** Constructor */
        public  AddressWrapper(){
            Street1 = '';
            Street2= '';
            city = 'Noida';
            state= '';
            pincode = '';
       }

    }
    public  class days{
        Integer Monday;
        Integer Tuesday;
        Integer Wednesday;
        Integer Thursday;
        Integer Friday;
        Integer Saturday;
        Integer Sunday;
    }
    public  class project{
        String Project_name;
        List<days> dayList = new List<days>();
    }
}
```

Main Apex class:

```java
public class UseDemoWrapper {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<DemoWrapper.Timesheet> fillWrapper(){
      /*List<DemoWrapper> dList = new List<DemoWrapper>();*/

        DemoWrapper.Timesheet t = new DemoWrapper.Timesheet(); 

        t.employeeId = '123456';
        t.employeeName = 'Niraj';
        
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper AD = NEW DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper AD1 = NEW DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper AD2 = NEW DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        
        t.Addresslist.add(AD); 
        t.Addresslist.add(AD1); 
        t.Addresslist.add(AD2);
        return t.Addresslist;
  
        DemoWrapper.Timesheet t1 = new DemoWrapper.Timesheet();
        
        t1.employeeId = '654321';
        t1.employeeName = 'Prashant';
        
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper Addr = new DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper Addr1 = new DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper Addr2 = new DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        
        system.debug(JSON.serialize(t));
               
        t1.Addresslist.add(Addr);
        t1.Addresslist.add(Addr1);
        t1.Addresslist.add(Addr2);
        
       
        system.debug(JSON.serialize(t1));
        
        DemoWrapper.Timesheet t2 = new DemoWrapper.Timesheet();
        t2.employeeId = '8978675';
        t2.employeeName = 'Sam';
        
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper L = new DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper L1 = new DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper L2 = new DemoWrapper.AddressWrapper();
        
        t2.Addresslist.add(L);
        t2.Addresslist.add(L1);
        t2.Addresslist.add(L2);
        
        system.debug(JSON.serialize(t2));
        List<DemoWrapper.Timesheet> Addresslist = new List<DemoWrapper.Timesheet>();
        Addresslist.add(t);
        Addresslist.add(t1);
        Addresslist.add(t2);
        system.debug(JSON.serialize(Addresslist));

    }

}
```

Aura component:

```
<aura:component controller="UseDemoWrapper implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initData}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="TimesheetWrapper" type="DemoWrapper[]"/>
    <!--<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>!-->

    Wrapper : {!v.TimesheetWrapper.length}

    <div class="slds-p-around--large">
        <h1 style="font-size:25px;">{!v.TimesheetWrapper.record.Name}</h1>
        <br/>

        <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="employee Id">employee Id</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="employee Name">employee Name</div>

                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Address list">Address list</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.TimesheetWrapper }" var="cont">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cont.employeeId}">{!cont.employeeId}</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cont.employeeName}">{!cont.employeeName}</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!cont.Addresslist}">{!cont.Addresslist}</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody> 
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```js
({
    initData : function(component, event, helper) {

        console.log('**In controller');
        helper.getWrapperdetails(component, event, helper);

    },
})
```

Helper.js

```js
({

    getWrapperdetails : function(component, event, helper) {

        console.log('**In helper');
        var a = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log('**In helper'+ a);

        var action = component.get('c.fillWrapper');
       /**  action.setParams({
            abc : component.get("v.recordId")
        }); */

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                alert("From server:" + response.getReturnValue());
                console.log('state' + 123);
                component.set("v.TimesheetWrapper", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log(JSON.stringify('response.TimesheetWrapper'));
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
})
```

Comment: While loading to the application page data is not coming from the server.I am using wrapper class .Can anyone suggest where I am missing to fetch the data from apex class

Comment: To access Apex wrapper class properties in Lightning Component you have to make them @AuraEnabled. Please check your wrapper class.

Comment: I have written @AuraEnabled

Comment: Check cmp file, at top `controller="UseDemoWrapper implements="` is written, check if that is a typo while pasting it here or it may be an issue in CMP file.

Comment: @NagendraSingh no its fine I have checked my code this is not giving an issue